# Grunt-Webdriver Warning: Object.keys called on non-object Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs

I get the error: 
Warning: Object.keys called on non-object Use --force to continue

... When I try the basic options usage example on:
https://github.com/webdriverjs/grunt-webdriver

What are the common causes of this error?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is now fixed with version `v0.3.2`

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I updated to the latest version of grunt-webdriver, but now I get a new error: events.js:72 throw er; // Unhandled 'error/event... My hunch is that I haven't set things up correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: could you please file another issue with the whole error stack? I will take a look on it